# How to get an overview of external links on a website in the shell?

Tags: links

I want to get an overview of external links on my websites. Ideally I want to control everything myself with open source tools I can run from my own laptop or server. I started playing around with some shell commands but I'm hoping there's something out there that works already. If not I'm happy to extend my shell script (and publish it on GitHub). Here are some lines...

```
D=example.com
wget -mk $D
grep href -are $D
```

Anything out there that already does what I want? Or something I can easily patch together?

Ideally I also want the anchor text and info whether the link is `nofollow` or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Lynx installed this is super easy to do with `lynx -dump -listonly http://example.com/somepage.html`

Comment: This is great! Would be nice to somehow also get anchor text and do/nofollow info.

Comment: For that you'd need to do something with regular expressions.